# Why Move file operation in java not providing reliable result?

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have 30 thread which is continuously running using fix interval scheduler.
Each thread responsible to move 2 file from input folder to output folder and server file name to another tool for processing.

Thread is calling following block of code written in synchronized method

```
Path movefrom = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(fileEntry.getPath());
Path target = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(ouputDirPath);
movedPath = Files.move(movefrom,target,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

In above code fileEntry is itreator for input folder represent single file at time.

This code is not producing reliable result as when i run this for 200 files there are  always 2 or 3 file I missed, as i mentioned thread calling another file processing tool and providing file name to it, expected to file already moved in output folder, but it always showing file not found exception for 2 or 3 files, I noticed file took too much time to move to output folder even size is in KB and each run having different files.
Issue is not reproducible for same file each time different files are failing out of 200.

Please direct me to correct direction to analyze this issue.

Additional information asked in comment--
OS/FS - windows
File which are failing to move is not throwing any exception.
Each time different files failed to move.

Comment: Define "2 or 3 files I missed"; is that 2 or 3 files you expected to be copied but were not, 2 or 3 files for which Files.move() fails (if yes, with what exception)?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, multi-threaded I/O to the same physical disk is usually a bad idea. The other bad idea is assuming that the state of a directory isn't going to change throughout your code. Particularly if your code does explicitly change the directory.

Comment: Can you try with the `ATOMIC_MOVE` flag?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle this will only work if 1. the FS supports it and 2. it occurs on the same FS; cross filesystem atomic moves don't exist (at least as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the network based file systems have really odd failure scenarios which basically require you to write verification code post operation code, just to really know if the operation succeeded.  You need to check if you are dealing with network mapped drives, if so you need to write your code to tolerate failure, perhaps by retrying if the file doesn't exist.

Have you checked your output file path?  I am guessing you have, but there is the rare chance that you are colliding in your output directory, with one file copying over another.

The information you provided in your question is specific and precise, but it is far from complete. I think you are focusing in on a few lines of code, insisting that they are the culprit.  Perhaps they are, but your focus is so narrow that if they are not, you may miss the root cause of the problem altogether.